# Socket issue when connecting to IRC

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, irc

I am trying create a very simple python bot that joins a specific channel, and says a random phrase every time someone says anything. I am doing this primarily to learn how sockets and IRC works. I am getting the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Classwork/Dropbox/Bots/Rizon Bot/ViewBot.py", line 36, in <module>
    irc.connect((irc_server, 6667))
  File "D:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Classwork\Dropbox\Bots\Rizon Bot\socks.py", line 351, in connect
    _orgsocket.connect(self,(self.__proxy[1],portnum))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When running the following code:

```
import random
from urlparse import urlparse
import socks
import socket
import time

#---- Definitions ----#
#Proxylist
proxy_list = []
with open("proxy_list.txt") as f:
    proxy_list = f.readlines()

#IRC Name List
irc_names = []
with open("irc_names.txt") as f:
    irc_names = f.readlines()

#Phrase List
phrase_list = []
with open("phrase_list.txt") as f:
    phrase_list = f.readlines()

irc_server = "irc.rizon.net"
irc_port = 6667
irc_channel = '#test12'  # Change this to what ever channel you would like


queue = 0
#---- Code ----#
proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
hostname = proxy.split(":")[0]
port = proxy.split(":")[1]
#irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc = socks.socksocket()
irc.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, hostname, port)
irc.connect((irc_server, 6667))
print irc.recv ( 4096 )
irc.send ( 'NICK ' + random.choice(irc_names) + '\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'USER botty botty botty :Sup\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'JOIN ' + irc_channel + '\r\n' )
time.sleep(4)
irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + irc_channel + ' :' + random.choice(phrase_list) + '\r\n')
while True:
   data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
   print data
   if data.find('KICK') != -1:
       irc.send('JOIN '+ irc_channel + '\r\n')
   if data.find('') != -1:  # !test command
       irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + irc_channel + ' :' + (random.choice(phrase_list)) + '\r\n')
```

I believe the issue is with:

```
irc.connect((irc_server, 6667))
```

My goal is to connect to the IRC server using a proxy loaded from the proxy list. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are determining the proxy port with

```
port = proxy.split(":")[1]
```

You are then passing it to socks:

```
irc.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, hostname, port)
```

But it's still a string. I bet it will work if you change the latter to

```
irc.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, hostname, int(port))
```

It's not actually *used* until you call `irc.connect` but it's the port from the setproxy.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
port = proxy.split(":")[1]
irc.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, hostname, port)
```

will result in port being a *string* containing the required port number. An `integer` is required for the port. Change your code to :

```
port = int(proxy.split(":")[1])
irc.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, hostname, port)
```

which converts the port from a string into an integer as required.